# randomness in lightgbm model training

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, lightgbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

What are the parameters that add randomness to the training of a lightgbm model? (for a large dataset) I have tried setting all parameters as default and letting **bin_construct_sample_cnt** be greater than the data size. But the models I trained are still different for different random seeds. It is also worth noting that I have confirmed **colsample_bytree** is 1.0 and **bagging_freq** is 0, which means there are no sampling of data or feature. What can be the other factors adding randomness to the training process that I did not notice?

Comment: Hi @kimo, welcome to the site. A Google search for "lightgbm non deterministic" shows potentially relevant matches. Have you checked them to see if they apply to your case?

Comment: Er... the same thing that gives randomness to Random Forest? Bootstrap and feature subset.

Comment: > the same thing that gives randomness to Random Forest?

That is not correct. By default, LightGBM considers all rows and all columns every time it adds a split to a tree.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be the other factors adding randomness to the training process that I did not notice?

By "adding randomness to the training process", I'm assuming that you mean things that could cause a different model to be produced by training runs with the following characteristics:

- identical training code
- identical training data

  - *including identical ordering of rows and columns*
- run on the same physical machine
- identical software

  - *e.g. `lightgbm`, its Python dependencies, OpenMP, etc.*
- identical available physical resources

  - *e.g. similar memory and CPU available to both training runs*

Given that all those things hold true, here are some reasons that consecutive training runs could produce different models:

- numerical precision differences caused by multi-threaded operations

  - *explanation: floating-point multiplication is only commutative up to a certain precision... changing the order that a set of floating-point number is multiplied by each other can change the final result. There is some randomness in which order threads complete, and therefore in what order their results might be multiplied*
  - *solution: set `deterministic=true` and `num_threads=1`*
  - *note: this will make training slower*
- numerical precision differences caused by how `Dataset` construction is performed

  - *explanation: LightGBM converts the raw training data into its preferred representation, the `Dataset`. It chooses how to parallelize that work (by column or by rows) by first doing a small bit of it and checking timings. Those timings and what they imply can change randomly based on what else is going on on the machine*
  - *solution: set `deterministic=true` and `force_row_wise=true`*
- you've asked LightGBM to do some sampling without providing a random seed

  - *explanation: LightGBM can optionally sample rows (`data_sample_strategy=bagging`, `bagging_fraction < 1.0`), columns (`feature_fraction < 1.0` or `feature_fraction_bynode < 1.0`), and splits (`extra_trees=true`). If you do not explicitly set a random seed, it'll choose different samples randomly on each run.*
  - *solution: set `seed != 0` if you change the values of any of those parameters*

See the following for more discusssion:

- https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5887#issuecomment-1545935847
- https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5913#issuecomment-1584636063